# React-leaflet LayersControl don't change name dynamically

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

we have a complex app with internationalization and I discovered that after language changes it didn't affect on LayersControl titles. 
Based on [react-leaflet docs](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/components#layerscontroloverlay) name is a static property.
Based on [Leaflet.js docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#control-layers) name is a key in a key value array of layers so it can't be changed by the lib structure.

So it isn't possible to fix this issue by contributing to react-leaflet and I ask you to help me to find out a suitable solution for this issue.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? You would like for instance to click a button and change from english to another language and have your `overlays names` to change accordingly?

Comment: Yep, it's exactly what I want. But we already have language setting and functioning i18n unlike <LayersControl.Overlay name="for_translate" /> which doesn't updates

Comment: Even if I'll run L.map.removeControl(ref) and then L.map.addControl(ref) - it'll still have the same names